# After Upgrade to Primefaces v6 from 5.3 getting Unable to find resource primefaces, primefaces.js

Tags: primefaces

After going from primefaces version 5.3 to v6 i am getting the warning:

```
Unable to find resource primefaces, primefaces.js.
```

I read that @ResourceDependency have to be changed. But where exactly in what file does this annotation have to be changed? Using search feature in IntelliJ i could not find the annotation anywhere.

Any advice welcome. 
Thanks

Comment: Where did you read _"

I read that @ResourceProperty have to be changed"_

Comment: sorry that was a typo: should have been ResourceDependency.

read it here :
https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Migration-Guide

Comment: You have another typo... same word... The `@ResourceDependency` change  is for the PrimeFaces special menu's in the elite themes if I remember correctly.

Comment: we are  not using any special menus or themes , but still seeing the warning. Like i mentioned the annotation @ResourceDependency i could not find anywhere in our code base

Comment: That is because it is in the PF source

Comment: so do we have to edit the PF source? which file is it that has to be edited?

Comment: No if you don't use any theme specific menus

Comment: ok, i have to revert. i double-checked, we are using a company-specific theme and i am sure that is why we are seeing this. Which file do i need to change in my editor to get rid of the warning? Thanks for all your answers so far

Comment: Read this again:  The `@ResourceDependency` change is for the PrimeFaces special menu's in the **elite themes** if I remember correctly.

Comment: well, assume the usage of an elite theme, how in that case would one have to proceed to get rid of the warning?

Comment: Elite theme **AND** its corresponding menu: Change the @ResourceDependency in the source of the menu. The source is received when buying the theme. But themes have gotten updates and these changes are in there